# I am getting a pretty different model when importing from makehuman into blender

Tags: import, makehuman

Other than searching Google (there doesn't seem to be a huge amount on this, most people in tutorials seem kind of oblivious to the fact that their model looks different) I have tried following this guide:

http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/Moving_Assets_into_Blender

It improved things a little (like the hair) but I still think it looks pretty different given that it's supposed to look like a friend of mine it's important that it looks the same.

Any suggestions?

Makehuman:

[image: MakeHuman]

Blender:

[image: Blender]

Comment: You are viewing the model in perspective mode in Blender, and ortho in Makehuman. You can probably just saturate the skin using nodes in blenderif he looks too pale.